# This method requires a body instead of a semicolon in main() in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[I m not able to find the problem so as the solution .need help stuck from 2days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6iEy.png)

[still there is problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja5AM.png)

Comment: You have a ";" after main method. Remove it, and error message is clearly saying same.

Comment: Please paste your program, your error message and your stack trace *as text into your question proper*. We don’t like links to images for several reasons. Many users here won’t follow the links at all, and often those considering writing an answer would like to paste your program into their own IDE. They can’t paste your image there.

Comment: Also which input did you type when you got the second error? See [How to Fix the Input Mismatch Exception in Java? - Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/blog/java-inputmismatchexception/).

Answer (score 1):

Please remove semicolon after method name

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is you put `;` in the main function. and some minor changes to be fix.

to solve this here how look it is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 int age = sc.nextInt();

 if (age > 18) {
  System.out.println("Adult");
 } else {
  System.out.println("Not Adult");
 }
}
```

best practice when you creating a file class it should be a PascalCase and followed by your class name also as PascalCase.